# Spring mvc:mapping path rules

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I need to map interceptor for all methods in annotated controller with @RequestMapping(value = "/client")

In mapping I have

```
<mvc:interceptor>
   <mvc:mapping path="/app/client/*"/>
   <bean class="com.cci.isa.web.CIPClientHandleInterceptor" />
</mvc:interceptor>
```

This interceptor called perfectly for urls like:
1. http://host/app/client/clientUpdateForm?clientId=305

But doesn't called for urls like:
2. http://host/app/client/clientUpdateForm/clientId_305 (with slash after method name)

How get it called for second variant?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you are using @RequestMapping annotation then I can't see why you are also specifying a mvc:interceptor. Just use <mvc:annotation-driven />...

Answer (score 6):

This question is too old, but maybe this helps somebody.

You should try removing `/app`, I think it's not necessary and perhaps this is causing the problem.

```
<mvc:mapping path="/client/**"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this will achieve what you would like:

```
<mvc:mapping path="/app/client/**/*"/>
```

The '/**' suggests any number of directories.  When this is used in conjunction with '/*', you have something that looks at an arbitrary folder depth, with an arbitrary file name.

Comment: No, interceptor doesn't called.<br/>
I tried use next combinations of path:<br/>
/app/client/**/*<br/>
/app/client/**<br/>
/app/client/*/*<br/>
No one of this variants doesn't call interceptor.

Comment: I am getting this error: Element mvc:mapping is not allowed here. Any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

If your controller with

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/client")
```

Try

```
<mvc:mapping path="/client**"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the above suggestion but change the annotation to

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/client*")
```

Although I would use two methods for each of the two URI patterns and pass them to the one common method to do the "stuff"...

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/app/client/clientUpdateFormat/{clientId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public String doItOne(@PathVariable("clientId") String clientId) {
    doItCommon(clientId);
```

and

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/app/client/clientUpdateFormat", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public String doItTwo(@RequestParam("clientId")  String clientId) {
    doItCommon(clientId);
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was, that we used custom RequestMappingHandlerMapping

```
<bean name="handlerMapping" 
class="utils.web.versioning.MobileVersionRewritingMappingHandler">
    <property name="order" value="0"/> 
    <property name="interceptors"> 
        <list> 
          ...
        </list> 
    </property>  
</bean>
```

XML or code config for CORS or any other MVC properties doesn't affect custom handler mappings.
I could specify cors config for custom handler mapping, but I prefer to remove legacy config and use this to configure interceptors:

```
 <mvc:interceptors>
  ...
 </mvc:interceptors>
```

Now cors is working and I'm using XML global cors configuration.